# can't get result from controller to my page in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-material

i can't get values from here to my page, i have used below code in controller

### controller

```
(function ()
  {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.manage-product')
    .controller('ManageProductController', ManageProductController);

/** @ngInject */
ManageProductController.$inject = ['$http', '$scope', '$mdDialog', '$document'];
function ManageProductController($http, $scope, $mdDialog, $document)
{
     var vm = this;

  $scope.composeDialog = function (ev)
    {
        vm.res=vm.result[ev];
        console.log(vm.res);
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller         : 'ManageProductController',
            controllerAs       : 'vm',  
            templateUrl        : 'app/main/apps/manage-product/compose-dialog.html',
            parent             : angular.element($document.body),
            targetEvent        : ev,
            //clickOutsideToClose: true
        });     
    }
   }
 })();
```

### form.html

```
<md-dialog-content ms-scroll>
        <md-input-container>
        <label>Product_Name</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.res.Product_Name">

        </input>
        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container>
            <label>Brand</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="ans.Brand">

        </input>

        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container>
            <label>Color</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.res.Color">
        </input>

        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container>
            <label>Price</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.res.Price">

        </input>

        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container>
            <label>Rating</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.res.Rating">

        </input>
```

Here i am using mdDialog, but i didn't use any child controller, i made it in same parent controller. i am getting values "console.log(vm.res)" here but i couldn't get it in page.

Comment: problem is you will have 2 instances of the controller, not one. Each will have separate scope. There are numerous ways to approach this. Use `scope` property of  `$mdDialog` or pass data to dialog using `locals` property. Or use a service to share data between the 2 instance of controllers. Or use a controller function instead of named controller.

Comment: Ha now i am using locals property, and the code is i have inserted to $mdDialog is "locals { item: vm.res }, and in html page i used item.Product_Name like this. Is it right?

Comment: i have on doubt is locals goes to controller or html form?

Comment: now i have only one controller, should i create child controller for dialog?

Answer (score 0):

I create one more dialog child controller and pass the locals value from parent controller and i got the result in form.